# Decoding eAccelerator PHP code?

Tags: php

Well I'm unsure if this is the correct site to use but how would I go about decoding/decrypting PHP code which is encoded/encrypted using eAccelerator?

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php /*This encoded file was generated using PHPCoder (http://phpcoder.sourceforge.net/) and eAccelerator (http://eaccelerator.sourceforge.net/)*/ if (!is_callable("eaccelerator_load") && !@dl("eAccelerator.so")) { die("This PHP script has been encoded using the excellent eAccelerator Optimizer, to run it you must install <a href=\"http://eaccelerator.sourceforge.net/\">eAccelerator or the eLoader</a>"); }eaccelerator_load('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'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would I go about decoding/decrypting PHP code which is
>   encoded/encrypted using eAccelerator?

You would have to reverse engineer the `eaccelerator_load()` function in eAccelerator.

[Note that this function only exists in older versions of eAccelerator.](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.eaccelerator.devel/381) For example, see here for the function as it existed in version 0.9.4: https://github.com/eaccelerator/eaccelerator/blob/e48010887b429a203bf03c7562e30a4d2bfa07d3/loader.c

The first thing the loader does is `base64_decode()` and `gzuncompress()` the string. You can see the (mostly plaintext) result of that here: http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/?results=744654407d52841255a5b54c1d5b402d

It looks like restoring that to more readable code will take a bit more work with analyzing the `eaccelerator_load()` function, but I'm sure you'll be up to the task :)

Comment: I assume there's no 'tool' out there to do this?

Comment: There's an online service for it: http://dezender.net/order/dezender/decompilation-ioncube-sourceguardian-zendoptimizer-phpexpress-eaccelerator-truebug.html

Comment: Yeah I found it too.. just that I'm a student and can't really afford the higher packages. /:

Comment: That's why I recommended reverse engineering it instead ;)

Comment: @JasonGeffner not even, it's open-source, just take a look and make the decrypting program! :D

Comment: @JasonGeffner Well I guess I'm too stupid for that. :3